# Different highlight JS and CSS in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I know how to change color of highlight of javascript and CSS. I add to my active **tm.Theme** file between `<array></array>` this strings:

```
    <dict>

    <key>name</key>

    <string>Embedded source</string>

    <key>scope</key>

    <string>text source, string.unquoted</string>

    <key>settings</key>

    <dict>

    <key>background</key>

    <string>#804A7D99</string>

    </dict>

    </dict>
```

Result:

[image: Violet background]

But how to make backgrounds of JS and CSS various that it was more convenient to be guided on minimap? For example:

**JS — blue**

[image: Blue background]

**CSS — green**

[image: Green background]

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed you have been looking into color schemes a lot over the last few days. Are you working on a release or just your personal setup?

Comment: Also - please provide [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/) or [**PasteBin**](http://pastebin.com/) code samples with your questions to make testing solutions easier for potential answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Include the following code in your `tmTheme` file to handle mixed `JS`, `CSS`, & `HTML`.

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>JS_Source</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.js.embedded.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#2D6A73</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#7B91B9</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>CSS_Source</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.css.embedded.html, meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#2D7333</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#7B91B9</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>HTML_Text</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#783727</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#7B91B9</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

As mentioned by [**@KeithHall**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall) in the comments, the use of the scopes:

```
CSS:   source.css.embedded.html, meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css
JS:    source.js.embedded.html
```

will allow you to apply these custom background colors to the `HTML` syntax without affecting the `CSS` & `JS` syntaxes.

Comment: note that this will also affect the background color of standalone css and js files - you could use the `source.css.embedded.html, meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css` scope to only affect css embedded in html and `source.js.embedded.html` to only affect js embedded in html

Comment: @KeithHall : Good call! Updated : )

Comment: @KeithHall where can I read about all scopes for HTML/CSS/JS apart from `source.css.embedded.html, meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css, text.html`, supported by Sublime Text 3? Thanks!

Comment: @СашаЧерных currently there is no documentation about scopes. You can use a package like [ScopeHunter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) to find out what scopes are used in specific places in your documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can add language specific sublime-settings (e.g `js.sublime-settings`) into `Sublime Text 3/Data/Packages/User` and define a completely different color scheme for this language (`js`).

```
{
    "color_scheme": "my_js_specific_theme.tmTheme",
}
```

or you can try the following in your `.tmTheme`:

```
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.js</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#000000</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Replace `#000000` with your color code of course.